# How can I delete conky from my system?

Tags: software-uninstall

I installed "conky" recently, but I'd like to unistall it now.
I tried:

```
sudo apt-get remove conky
sudo apt-get purge conky
```

After running these commands were, I can still run conky from the terminal.

How can I actually remove it?

Comment: Open a new terminal and run that code.

Comment: How did you install conky ? I am guessing not with apt-get. What version of Ubuntu ?

Comment: ubuntu 16.04, i installed from source package

Comment: Download the source again, go into its directory, run './configure` then run `sudo make uninstall` if you were lucky, it will work and uninstall it.

Comment: If that does not work you will have to manually remove it by deleting the files it installed. In the future this is a reason to use apt, ie apt-get or package manager.

Comment: Judging by solfish's own answer, they did install using APT

Answer (score 5):

Finally, I found a solution,

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove conky conky-all
```

Thanks for your efforts :)

Comment: If this is the solution that worked for you, please accept it. You seem to have accepted an answer that is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score -1):

if those commands didn't work just install Synaptic Package Manager

`sudo apt-get install synaptic`.

It is a very useful tool for downloading, installing and removing packages I tried it on my conky and it worked like charm.

Edit:
Edited this answer because I don't have enough reputation to join in the conversation bellow. There are multiple conky packages: conky, conky-all, conky-std. If you installed `sudo apt-get install conky-all`, then you can't uninstal just conky you have to run `sudo apt-get purge conky-all`, try that.

Comment: thanks but  is there any way by using terminal?

Comment: Ah, got it it's actually named 'conky-std' so just run sudo apt-get purge cokny-std

Comment: apt-get will not work, OP installed from source.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen apparently not, looking at the self-answer... When they said "source package" I think they meant "package from a source [where packages come from such as an apt repository]"

Comment: @Zanna - Well the point is apt-get will not work if a package is installed outside of APT (apt-get or software center). The OP posted conflicting information so as long as you understand my point about installing packages outside of APT ;) FWIW I did NOT downvote this answer

Comment: @bodhi.zazen of course :) it was just a (probably overzealous) fyi, I was trying to clean up the whole page which is a bit of a mess now with accepted link-only answer and lots of confusing comments. Not sure what to do. By the way Daniel, you can always comment on your own posts regardless of reputation

Comment: @Zanna Yeah, I know, but they were having conversation in the answer below which I couldn't join.